# Remember Window Dimension / Position Single Screen Laptop

Tags: macos, window-manager

Is there any way to have windows remember where they were and how big they were on OSX?

I've tried the suggestions in this discussion but it's still not working.

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5471042?tstart=30

Comment: OS X should remember window positions—it always does for me… what app/situation doesn't it work for?

Comment: Windows switch size and or position for me when I adjust the resolution of my monitor or if I (un)plug an external monitor. Are you doing either of these?

Comment: For instance, open Terminal, stick it somewhere on the desktop, stretch it out for the long commands I use, close it ... open it again sometime later ... repeat move and stretch ... basic window management imho ...

Comment: I do exactly that with Terminal i.e move and stretch it. It always remembers. Must application windows in OS X have a `Auto save`  in their framework. This is used to save the position and bounds ( frame rectangle ) of the windows in the preference file of the app. Terminal and finder both use this.

Comment: This is really odd, neither of my apps (Terminal or Finder) ever save their position or size ... I wonder what I've done to break that?

Comment: Hmm, I've just got Terminal to remember the screen size but I had to use the Shell>Use Settings As Default menu option ...

Comment: No such luck with Finder though ... so far ...

Comment: How are you opening windows in finder.

Comment: Just clicking on finder.

Comment: I mean folder on desktop or folder in window..

Comment: Ahh, I think I get what you're alluding to, each folder has it's own setup?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a tool like [Divvy](https://mizage.com/divvy/) to position and remember window positions. OS X simply doesn't handle it in an ideal manner.

Comment: Hmm ... more apps to do what the OS should be doing.  Coming from the windows world I'm constantly surprised by things like this.  Thanks Dave.

Comment: Do not see where it remembers windows?

Comment: yeah, Divvy can help you manage windows, but doesn't seem to have a way to remember window positions.

Comment: Hmm ... I'm less impressed with OSX by the day.

Comment: @Jammer No shit. Window management is horrible. I am stuck at this moment though. Windows is probably best out there. Already been at linux. Not going back. Too much invested into mac, now.